# How to profile a python program that doesn't end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, runtime, profiling

I have python code of a server and client that do some operations but the operations can take days and even weeks at a time.
in most runs the program takes up 100% cpu and I want to know why.
I don't have the means to stop it mid run and I need some way to point out the lines that take the most processing power.

Iv'e tried searching for different profilers online but none of them give any output before the program is terminated successfully(in my case even when the run ends there are still threads unterminated so the program doesn't end until I manually end it with C-c)

What I need is some what to have profiling data before the program ends, if that's possible.

Comment: A starting point will be to isolate what operations are taking longer by reducing code size, and look at [memprof](https://pypi.org/project/memprof/) for e.g

Answer (score 0):

With [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) you can profile a running python program (by passing in a pid), and get results back while it's running.